APT: Skip optical drive
Is there a hotkey that skips the optical drive?
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 ...
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter]

I do not want to kill the process.
I want to break this loop:

What caused it:
I did enter apt-get install apache2 apache2-utils.
I have never edited /etc/apt/sources.list on this box.

What Linux-based distribution? Are you using a graphical interface or are you entirely command line based?

It's Debian with Xfce.

Why was my question voted down? May somebody elaborate, please? It is not constructive to vote down without an explanation.

The system must have been installed from local media, in which case the installer automatically adds a reference for it to /etc/apt/sources.list.
To get rid of the prompts, just comment it out.
If you have other repositories configured, then I think you can just press Enter to the prompt without inserting the media, and let the disc access attempt fail.

I cannot break the loop with . Have a look at the new screenshot, please.

@viator It doesn't matter if you break the loop or not, because APT will recheck the dependency loop when you go to restart the install, and on top of that TelcoM is correct in telling you to remove the line starting with cdrom: but trying to do so with the loop constantly repeating results in This file is being used by another process. so please break the loop.
